# Add language to Google Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages, huawei, customization, gboard

I have a Huawei G8 and hate this phone. Can't use Google Keyboard because on this phone it is not supporting Georgian language. Is there any ways to add Georgian keyboard in Gboard? Thanks and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Huawei phones restrict google keyboard/Gboard languages based on regions. I am also having same problem, but so far could not find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Open your keyboard and to to its settings (tap on "Google" icon at the top, then on cog icon).
Then go to "Languages" and you'll see a list of all available languages there. My phone has two variants of Georgian keyboard (QWERTY and Typewriter).

Comment: I know how to see language list and surely know that Gboard supports Georgian, but on Huawei device, it's not listed.  I've tried Morelocatione2 and nothing. have downloaded dictionary ad on in Gboard and still can't use it

Comment: I see. It looks like certain phone models do not feature some languages that others do. I can see two versions of Georgian language on my phone. It may be because either there is no official support for the language, and it was added by my phone manufacturer, or because your phone lacks some API that enables support of Georgian. So far I'm unable to find out which of the two is true, and will continue the search. In the meantime, I suggest trying different virtual keyboard app.

Comment: @IvaZakareishvili I'm also assuming that you are running the latest available Gboard on you device.

Comment: For some reason I was not able to answer this question, so I comment on this one. I had a similar problem with my P10, and got around it by set Gboard to use the system language. If this is not the desired keyboard language, add a secondary system language. Gboard does now have a world icon to change the language. If you use a current version of Gboard it has this annoying feature of multilingual suggestions for text correction, but you can turn this off in the settings. Gboard will remember in which language you typed the last time. Hope this helps